# EF adds null-check on parameter using nvarchar

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-framework, linq, nvarchar

Im using EF 6.4.4 and Oracle 12.2.0.1

Table1.Id is varchar2(32), and I have a linq query like this:

```
string tmp = "randomtext/"
var stringList = (from t in _context.Table1
select new Model1
{
   SomeText = tmp + t.Id
}).ToList();
```

The sql generated adds a null-check and uses nvarchar:

```
select ((CASE WHEN ('randomtekst/' IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE 'randomtekst/' END)
       || ("table1"."ID")) AS "C1"
```

Note the **N''**

This results in a *ORA-12704: character set mismatch* error.

I have tried adding [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)] on the Model1.SomeText property, and also [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR2")] on the Table1.Id property, to no effect.

Is it possible to avoid the null check all together, or if not so, at least avoid the use of nvarchar?

Comment: Windows and .NET strings are Unicode, specifically UTF16. `tmp` is a *parameter* as far as the query is concerned. That parameter is a Unicode string, so the query needs to use `nvarchar`.

Comment: As for why the Oracle provider generates this query - which Oracle provider are you using? Oracle's? Devart's? Someone else's? You could avoid this confusion if you loaded the IDs first and generated the `Model1` instances afterwards, eg `_context.Table1.Select(t=>t.Id).ToList().Select(id=>new Model1{ SomeText = $"{tmp}{id}"});`. This will result in a simpler query and reduce the bandwidth used - instead of returing a string including th e prefix, only the IDs are returned

Comment: Thanks for the insights!
We are using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 19.7.0
Actually I would like to pass the queryable to odata, so thats why I cant concat the strings afterwards.

Comment: Oracle's .NET providers always have interesting issues (apart from the size) which is why people often use other providers. In this case it seems it got confused and tried to treat `tmp` both as a value *and* a parameter. Separate the ID retrieval from model generation to avoid the problem.

Comment: what happens if you do this `SomeText = "randomtext/" + t.Id`

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty That actually works fine, and no null-check is added. However that's not an option for me, as I retrieve the text elsewhere from into a variable. As mentioned above, it might be about how the Oracle provider interprets values and parameters.

Comment: For a temporary fix I would suggest get all the records and loop thorough it and append the text you need.